# unable to insert users registration details into the database

Tags: php

i cannot insert users into database after registration, i have done all i can but was not successful, i really neddd help here, please i want to know and what am doing wrong in my script.

this is my registration html script:

```
<span class='details' ><h1><bold>ENTER YOUR DETAILS HERE</bold></h1></span>

  <form action="trotle.php"  method="POST">            


              <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;">
              <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="enter your id" required />
                </div><br>


               <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;">

              <label>fullname</label>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter your fullname" required />
                </div><br>

                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;">

              <label>username</label>

                  <input type="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required />
                </div><br>



                <div class="form-group" >
                   <label>password</label>

                 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"  placeholder="type in your password" required />
                </div>

              <br>
              <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;" />
                <label>email</label>

                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"  placeholder="Enter your email" required />
                </div><br>

                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;">
                <label>country</label>

                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country"  placeholder="Enter your country" required />
                </div><br>


                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;">
                <label>phone number</label>

                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phonenumber"  placeholder="Enter your phonenumber" required />
                </div><br>

                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;">
                <label>Alternative phone number</label>

                  <input type="number" class="form-control" name="alternativephonenumber"  placeholder="Enter your alternative phonenumber" required />
                </div><br>


              <div class="form-group"  style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;">
                <label>referrer</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="referrer" placeholder="type in who referred you here" required />
                </div><br>


              <div class="form-group"  style="margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;"">
                <label>paymentmode</label>

                  <select name="paymentmode" class="form-control" required />
<option value="">Select your paymentmode</option>
<option value="bitcoin">bitcoin</option>
<option value="perfectmoney">perfectmoney</option>
<option value="naira">naira</option>

                  </select>

                </div>
                <br>

           <div class="form-group" style='text-align: center;padding-top: 30px;'>

              <input type="checkbox" style=" vertical-align: sub; margin-left: 120px;margin-bottom: -15px; " required><a href="homepage.php">  I agree with </a><a href='../terms' target="_blank">Terms and conditions</a><br>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit_signup" value='REGISTER' style="margin-left:145px;border:none; margin-bottom: -10px; background-color: green; font-weight: bold;border-style: dotted;">
              <a href="trotle.php"><input type="post" class="btn btn-success" value='LOGIN' style="margin-left:140px;background-color: green; font-weight: bold;border-style: dotted; border-color:black ;padding: 5px; size:20px; margin-bottom:-10px;"></a>
              </div>
              <br>
              <?php


              ?>
              </form>
```

my php script for inserting users into database is below;

```
<?php
$id=$fullname=$username=$password=$email=$country= $phonenumber=$alternativephonenumber=$referrer=$paymentmode="";
if(isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('submit_signup',$_POST))   
{  
$id= $_POST['id'];
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id= $_POST['id'];  

}
$fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
$fullname= $_POST['fullname'];  
}
else{
    echo 'please enter your fullname';
}
$username= $_POST['username'];
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$username= $_POST['username'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your username';
}
$password= $_POST['password'];
if(isset($_POST['password'])){
$password= $_POST['password'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your password';
}
$email= $_POST['email'];
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email= $_POST['email'];    
}
else{
    echo 'enter your email';
}
$country= $_POST['country'];
if(isset($_POST['country'])){
$country= $_POST['country'];    
}
else{
    echo 'enter your country';
}
$phonenumber= $_POST['phonenumber'];
if(isset($_POST['phonenumber'])){
$phonenumber= $_POST['phonenumber'];    
}
else{
    echo 'enter your phonenumber';
}
$alternativephonenumber= $_POST['alternativephonenumber'];
if(isset($_POST['alternativephonenumber'])){
$alternativephonenumber= $_POST['alternativephonenumber'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your alternativephonenumber';
}
$referrer= $_POST['referrer'];
if(isset($_POST['referrer'])){
$referrer= $_POST['referrer'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your referrer';
}
$paymentmode= $_POST['paymentmode']; 
if(isset($_POST['paymentmode'])){
$paymentmode= $_POST['paymentmode'];    
}
else{var_dump($_POST['id']);
    echo 'enter your paymentmode';
}
}
    else {
        echo 'nah';

    }

    $serverhost='localhost';
$serverdb='charles';
$serveruser='root';
$serverpassword='';




try{ 
    $connect= new PDO("mysql:host=$serverhost;dbname=charles;" , $serveruser, $serverpassword);
 $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     } 
      catch( PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getmessage();
        }

     if($connect){
        echo 'database successful!';
     }


$sql="INSERT INTO users(id, fullname, username, password, email, country, phonenumber, alternativephonenumber, referrer, paymentmode)VALUES(:id, :fullname, :username, :password, :email, :country, :phonenumber, :alternativephonenumber, :referrer, :paymentmode)";

$query=$connect->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':phonenumber', $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':alternativephonenumber', $alternativephonenumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':referrer', $referrer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':paymentmode', $paymentmode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();





?>
```

Comment: any errors while execution?

Comment: the `id` field is hidden so how is the user to enter a value?

Comment: @kuru, no errors while execution

Comment: @RamRaider, id field is not meant to be entered by users, remember database updates id by itself

Answer (score 0):

Change you PHP script like this and try, if you not getting the error it might be your validation is wrong

```
$id=$fullname=$username=$password=$email=$country= $phonenumber=$alternativephonenumber=$referrer=$paymentmode="";
if(isset($_POST['submit_signup']))  //simplified validation 
{  

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id= $_POST['id'];  

}

if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
$fullname= $_POST['fullname'];  
}
else{
    echo 'please enter your fullname';
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$username= $_POST['username'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your username';
}

if(isset($_POST['password'])){
$password= $_POST['password'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your password';
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$email= $_POST['email'];    
}
else{
    echo 'enter your email';
}

if(isset($_POST['country'])){
$country= $_POST['country'];    
}
else{
    echo 'enter your country';
}

if(isset($_POST['phonenumber'])){
$phonenumber= $_POST['phonenumber'];    
}
else{
    echo 'enter your phonenumber';
}

if(isset($_POST['alternativephonenumber'])){
$alternativephonenumber= $_POST['alternativephonenumber'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your alternativephonenumber';
}

if(isset($_POST['referrer'])){
$referrer= $_POST['referrer'];  
}
else{
    echo 'enter your referrer';
}

if(isset($_POST['paymentmode'])){
$paymentmode= $_POST['paymentmode'];    
}
else{var_dump($_POST['id']);
    echo 'enter your paymentmode';
}
}
    else {
        echo 'nah';

    }

    $serverhost='localhost';
$serverdb='charles';
$serveruser='root';
$serverpassword='';




try{ 
    $connect= new PDO("mysql:host=$serverhost;dbname=$serverdb;" , $serveruser, $serverpassword);
 $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     } 
      catch( PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getmessage();
        }

     if($connect){
        echo 'database successful!';
     }


$sql="INSERT INTO users(id, fullname, username, password, email, country, phonenumber, alternativephonenumber, referrer, paymentmode)VALUES(:id, :fullname, :username, :password, :email, :country, :phonenumber, :alternativephonenumber, :referrer, :paymentmode)";

$query=$connect->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':phonenumber', $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':alternativephonenumber', $alternativephonenumber, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':referrer', $referrer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':paymentmode', $paymentmode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Changes made:

1. Simplified the validation
2. Removed unnecessary assignment of variables, if you are using `isset` then don't assign it out side the `isset`
3. Update your db name with variable for the db name

Last advise, if you are echo the validation error for testing it's fine, otherwise hold in a variable and echo it in the proper place. And take your insert query code block inside the validation.

Comment: i have done all of that you suggested but is still not inserting into the database, am really confused, can you pls help me examine more to find if there are any errors, thank you.

Comment: if you are using id as auto increment, remove from your insert query, other  occurrences and try

Answer (score 0):

Rather than unmanagable, inline styles, use css and assign the styles with classes, ids or parent>child selectors etc.

DIV elements do not use the `/` at the end of the tag ( see the email section in original code )

There is no input type `POST` ( `<input type="post" class="btn btn-success" value='LOGIN'... />` ) - presumably a button would be better?

The `id` field is hidden in the HTML but presumably the db uses an `auto-increment` field ( Primary Key ) for this so it is not necessary to send this value - the user would not know this before submitting the form and there would be nothing to prevent them using any number they wanted potentially,

```
<style>
    .form-group{margin-left:50px;color:#000099; font-family:times;}
    .form-control{}
    input[type='checkbox']{vertical-align: sub; margin-left: 120px;margin-bottom: -15px;}
    input[type='submit']{margin-left:145px;border:none; margin-bottom: -10px; background-color: green; font-weight: bold;border-style: dotted;}
    input[type='button']{margin-left:140px;background-color: green; font-weight: bold;border-style: dotted; border-color:black ;padding: 5px; size:20px; margin-bottom:-10px;}
</style>


<span class='details' >
   <h1>
      <bold>ENTER YOUR DETAILS HERE</bold>
   </h1>
</span>

<form action='trotle.php' method='POST'>

   <!-- HOW does a user enter a value here if it is HIDDEN??? Removed `required` attribute -->
   <div class='form-group'>
      <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name='id' placeholder='enter your id' />
   </div>
   <br>

   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>fullname</label>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' name='fullname' placeholder='Enter your fullname' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>username</label>
      <input type='username' class='form-control' name='username' placeholder='Enter your username' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group' >
      <label>password</label>
      <input type='password' class='form-control' name='password' placeholder='type in your password' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>email</label>
      <input type='email' class='form-control' name='email'  placeholder='Enter your email' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>country</label>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' name='country' placeholder='Enter your country' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>phone number</label>
      <input type='number' class='form-control' name='phonenumber' placeholder='Enter your phonenumber' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>Alternative phone number</label>
      <input type='number' class='form-control' name='alternativephonenumber' placeholder='Enter your alternative phonenumber' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>referrer</label>
      <input type='text' class='form-control' name='referrer' placeholder='type in who referred you here' required />
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <label>paymentmode</label>
      <select name='paymentmode' class='form-control' required />
         <option value=''>Select your paymentmode</option>
         <option value='bitcoin'>bitcoin</option>
         <option value='perfectmoney'>perfectmoney</option>
         <option value='naira'>naira</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <!-- this checkbox needs a name!! Assign name `terms` -->
      <input type='checkbox' name='terms' required />
      <a href='homepage.php'>  I agree with </a><a href='../terms' target='_blank'>Terms and conditions</a>
      <br>
      <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='submit_signup' value='REGISTER' />
      <a href='trotle.php'>
        <input type='button' class='btn btn-success' value='LOGIN' />
      </a>
   </div>
   <br>
</form>





<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit_signup'] ) ){
        /* id should be an auto-increment field in the db */
        $id = isset( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
        $fullname = isset( $_POST['fullname'] ) ? $_POST['fullname'] : false;
        $username = isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
        $password = isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $_POST['password'] : false;
        $email = isset( $_POST['email'] ) ? $_POST['email'] : false;
        $country = isset( $_POST['country'] ) ? $_POST['country'] : false;
        $phonenumber = isset( $_POST['phonenumber'] ) ? $_POST['phonenumber'] : false;
        $alternativephonenumber = isset( $_POST['alternativephonenumber'] ) ? $_POST['alternativephonenumber'] : false;
        $referrer = isset( $_POST['referrer'] ) ? $_POST['referrer'] : false;
        $paymentmode = isset( $_POST['paymentmode'] ) ? $_POST['paymentmode'] : false;




        $errors=array();
        if( !$fullname )$errors[]='please enter your fullname';
        if( !$username )$errors[]='enter your username';
        if( !$password )$errors[]='enter your password';
        if( !$email )$errors[]='enter your email';
        if( !$country )$errors[]='enter your country';
        if( !$phonenumber )$errors[]='enter your phonenumber';
        if( !$alternativephonenumber )$errors[]='enter your alternativephonenumber';
        if( !$referrer )$errors[]='enter your referrer';
        if( !$paymentmode )$errors[]='enter your paymentmode';


        if( !empty( $errors ) ){

            /* display any errors with form submission */
            foreach( $errors as $error ){
                echo $error . '<br />';
            }

        } else {

            try{

                $serverhost='localhost';
                $serverdb='charles';
                $serveruser='root';
                $serverpassword='';


                $connect=new PDO("mysql:host={$serverhost};dbname={$serverdb};" , $serveruser, $serverpassword);
                $connect->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );


                if( $connect ){

                    $sql="insert into `users`
                            ( `fullname`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `country`, `phonenumber`, `alternativephonenumber`, `referrer`, `paymentmode` )
                            values
                            ( :fullname, :username, :password, :email, :country, :phonenumber, :alternativephonenumber, :referrer, :paymentmode )";

                    $stmt=$connect->prepare( $sql );

                    if( $stmt ){

                        $stmt->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':country', $country, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':phonenumber', $phonenumber );
                        $stmt->bindParam(':alternativephonenumber', $alternativephonenumber );
                        $stmt->bindParam(':referrer', $referrer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindParam(':paymentmode', $paymentmode, PDO::PARAM_STR);

                        $result = $stmt->execute();
                        echo $result ? 'success' : 'fail';
                    }
                }
            } catch( PDOException $e ) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: thanks @Ramraider for your help but is still not inserting, although it shows a success message but not user was inserted, what will i do next plz, i want to get this right and know it

Comment: no, the message it showed was 'success' as you indicated in the script if it were successful, but no insertion

Comment: I just setup a full end to end test for the above ( with only minor edits to suit database ) and it worked fine.

Comment: thanks to you all guys, i have resolved the issue, i can now insert users into my database, a special thank you @RamRaider for giving me a detailed helped. love you guys

Comment: thanks to you all guys, i have resolved the issue, i can now insert users into my database, a special thank you @RamRaider for giving me a detailed helped. love you guys